# Is it possible to crawl SharePoint Online from SharePoint Server 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, crawling, sharepoint-on-prem, content-source

We can't configure hybrid search since the index will reside in the cloud. The one-way outbound search has the problem of seperate result blocks.

Has anyone tried to crawl SharePoint Online from SharePoint Server 2013?

I think about it that way:

1. Change the crawl account to a synced account
2. Give the crawl account full read in SharePoint Online
3. Create a new content source (Web Site or SharePoint Site)

Is there a statement from Microsoft that it's not possible or not recommended?

Comment: I think it is. Have you tried configuring it?

Comment: I tried but always got time outs and some errors about the robot.txt (what shouldn't be the reason to fail). I tried to crawl as website and as SharePoint Site. No success.